# Embeddable with @ManyToOne and AccessType.Property on Id field

Tags: spring, jpa

I am trying to define a `@Embeddable` class with a `@ManyToOne` relationship to another entity. The `@OneToMany` side has a `@Id` field annotated with `@Access(AccessType.Property)`. Here is an example code to illustrate:

```
@Embeddable
class Embeddable {
    @ManyToOne
    private ClassA classA;
}

@Entity
class ClassA implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Access(AccessType.Property)
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() { return id; }
}

@Entity
class ClassB {
    @ElementCollection
    private List<Embeddable> embeddables;
}
```

The problem is that the created table definition for the class `Embeddable` seems to be wrong. The column for `ClassA` is of type `bytea` and is named `class_a` instead of `bigint` and `class_a_id`. Also if i try to persist one dataset the related entity of ClassA is saved serialized as hex..Every other `@Entity` works as expected. Is this a bug or an error on my part?

**Edit:**
Table for Embeddable (current state):

```
| class_b_id | class_a     |
| type: int  | type: typea |
|:-----------|------------:|
| 123        | A3B4738D..  |
```

Table for Embeddable (needed state):

```
| class_b_id | class_a_id  |
| type: int  | type: int   |
|:-----------|------------:|
| 123        | 2           |
```

Comment: I don't really get it. Could you add the _is_-state of your schema and the _wanted_-state of the schema to your question?

Comment: @Clijsters i added my is and wanted state for my schema.